# How do I implement polymorphism in Scala

Tags: oop, scala

I've been learning Scala for web-development for quite some time, and I have stumbled upon a lack of interfaces. Coming from PHP, I used interfaces quite a lot for method-level polymorphism and IoC like this:

```
interface iAnimal
{
    function makeVoice();
}

class Cat implements iAnimal
{
    function makeVoice()
    {
        return "Meow";
    }
}

class Dog implements iAnimal
{
    function makeVoice()
    {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

class Box
{
    private $_animal;

    function __construct(iAnimal $animal)
    {
        $this->_animal = $animal;         
    }

    function makeSound()
    {
        echo $this->_animal->makeVoice();
    }
}
```

And so on, and that was an easy way to ensure that anything I passed to the `Box` object had a `makeVoice` method that I was calling elsewhere. Now, what I'm curious of, is how do I implement similar functionality with Scala. I tried searching for this, but info is quite scarce. The only answer I found was to use traits, but as far as I know, they are used for concrete implementation, not declaration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question, as such,  has little to do with inversion of control and a lot to do with polymorphism.. you might want to rephrase it.

Comment: You're right. I've mistaken Dependency Inversion with IoC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per other answers, the solution is to use traits :

```
trait Animal {
  def makeVoice(): Unit //no definition, this is abstract!
}

class Cat extends Animal{
  def makeVoice(): Unit = "Meow"
}
class Dog extends Animal{
  def makeVoice(): Unit = "Woof"
}

class Box(animal:Animal) {
  def makeSound() = animal.makeVoice()
}
```

A `trait` in Scala will be directly compiled to an `interface` in Java.  If it contains any concrete members then these will be directly copied into any class that inherits from the trait.  You can happily use a Scala trait as an interface from Java, but then you don't get the concrete functionality mixed in for you.

---

However... this is only part of the picture. What we've implemented so far is subtype polymorphism, Scala also allows for ad-hoc polymorphism (a.k.a typeclasses):

```
// Note: no common supertype needed here
class Cat { ... }
class Dog { ... }

sealed trait MakesVoice[T] {
  def makeVoice(): Unit
}
object MakesVoice {
  implicit object CatMakesVoice extends MakesVoice[Cat] {
    def makeVoice(): Unit = "Meow"
  }
  implicit object DogMakesVoice extends MakesVoice[Dog] {
    def makeVoice(): Unit = "Woof"
  }
  //helper method, not required, but nice to have
  def makesVoice[T](implicit mv: MakesVoice[T]) = mv
}

import MakesVoice._
//context-bound version
class Box[T : MakesVoice] {
  //using a helper:
  def makeSound() = makesVoice[T].makeVoice()
  //direct:
  def makeSound() = implicitly(MakesVoice[T]).makeVoice()
}

//using an implicit param
class Box[T](implicit mv : MakesVoice[T]) {
  def makeSound() = mv.makeVoice()
}
```

What's important here is that the `MakesVoice` type class can be associated with *any* type regardless of what hierarchies it belongs to. You can even use type classes with primitives or types imported from a 3rd party library that you couldn't possibly retrofit with new interfaces.

Of course, you have parametric polymorphism as well, which you'd probably know better as "generics" :)

Comment: Very nice comment, but a little mind-blowing, as is Scala in general. `implicit` is a very strong sorcery, and takes quite some time to get used to.

Comment: They're safe enough, you just need to use them sensibly and with a bit of discipline - much the same as *any* language feature.  So type classes are good, enriching types is fine, but abusing implicit conversion on common types is very very bad,

Answer (score 1):

Traits are used for both declaration and concrete implementation. Here is a direct translation of your example

```
trait Animal {
  def makeVoice()
}

class Cat extends Animal{
  override def makeVoice(): Unit = "Meow"
}
class Dog extends Animal{
  override def makeVoice(): Unit = "Woof"
}

class Box(animal:Animal) {
  def makeSound()={
    animal.makeVoice()
  }
}
```

Additionally, you are able to actually define a concrete implementation directly in the trait which is useful for behaviours shared by members of different class hierarchies:

```
trait Fish{
  def swim()="Swim"
}
class Truit extends Fish 

trait Bird{
  def fly() = "Fly"
}
class Eagle extends Bird

class Duck extends ???{
  def swim=???
  def fly=???
}
```

The duck both swims ans flies, you could define it as such :

```
trait Swimmer{
  def swim
}
trait Fish extends Swimmer{
  def swim()="Swim"
}
class Truit extends Fish 
trait Bird{
  def fly()="Fly"
}
class Eagle extends Bird

class Duck extends Bird with Swimmer
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer.